# Call php class method from string with parameter

Tags: php

I am having trouble calling a **class method** from a string in PHP. Here's a simple example. Once I get this working I'll be using a variable as the method name.

Here's how I'd be calling the method normally:

```
$tags_array = $this->get_tags_for_image($row["id"]);
```

Here's how I'm trying but getting an error:

```
$tags_array = call_user_func('get_images_for_tag', $row["id"]);
```

I must be missing the scope but I can't figure out how to call the method.

----EDIT
Figured out that this calls the method but **$row** is undefined now I believe

```
$tags_array = call_user_func(array($this, 'get_images_for_tag'), $row["id"]);
```

Full code block:

```
 $images = call_user_func(array($this, 'get_images_for_tag'), $filter);
        foreach ($images as $row){

            $tags_array = call_user_func(array($this, 'get_images_for_tag'), $row["id"]);
            foreach ($tags_array as $tag_row){
                $tags_array[] =  $tag_row["tag"];
            }

            $image_array []= array (
                'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . '/'. $row["name"],
                'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . '/thumbs/' . 't_'. $row["name"],
                'id' => $row["id"],
                'description' => $row["description"],
                //'url' => $row["url"],
                'tags' => $tags_array
                );
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you want to call a method on an object with [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)() you have to pass it an array with the first element as the object or class name that the method will be called on and the second element being the name of the method, e.g.:

```
$tags_array = call_user_func( array($this,'get_images_for_tag'), $row["id"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$tags_array = call_user_func(array($yourClassObj, 'get_images_for_tag'), $row["id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

call_user_method('get_images_for_tag',$this,$row["id"]);