# make a reference to a method in a class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call php class method from string with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531019/call-php-class-method-from-string-with-parameter)

I am trying to call a method in a class from a string of the method and a string of the class, by means of `call_user_func_array()`

For Example:

```
$class = 'Posts';
$classObj = new $class();
$func = 'makePost';
$params = array('something', 'somethingelse');
call_user_func_array($classObj->$func, $params);
```

This does not work for me. :C

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use an `array`, with the first item being the object, and the second being a string of the function name you want to call:

```
call_user_func_array( array( $classObj, $func), $params);
```

This is an example of using a [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) in PHP.